# Nullpointer on FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I'm getting FirebaseRemoteConfig instance through MainActivity.onCreate.
It is simple setupCode but a crash is happening on production on some devices. This is the stacktrace. I'm using playservices 9.0.1.

Any thoughts?

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setupFirebaseRemoteConfig(); //line 476
  }


  private void setupFirebaseRemoteConfig() {

          mFirebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();

          FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings configSettings = new FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder()
                  .setDeveloperModeEnabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                  .build();

          mFirebaseRemoteConfig.setConfigSettings(configSettings);
          mFirebaseRemoteConfig.setDefaults(R.xml.remote_config);

          configCacheExpiration = 3600;

          if (mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getInfo().getConfigSettings().isDeveloperModeEnabled()) {
              configCacheExpiration = 0;
          }
      }

  Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{}:

  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaji$zzc.zzbTG' on a null object reference
         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2658)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
  Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaji$zzc.zzbTG' on a null object reference
         at com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig.zza(Unknown Source)
         at com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig.zzbD(Unknown Source)
         at com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance(Unknown Source)
         at com.buscaalimento.android.view.viewcontroller.MainActivity.setupFirebaseRemoteConfig(MainActivity.java:476)
         at com.buscaalimento.android.view.viewcontroller.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:455)
         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6221)
         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2611)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Comment: what is code at this line com.buscaalimento.android.view.viewcontroller.MainActivity.setupFirebaseRemoteConfig(MainActivity.java:476) ?

Comment: I edited and added the code @Shubhank. Thanks

Comment: still you need to tell that line code since i don't know line numbers in your code

Comment: I added a comment with the line code. But it is the call inside onCreate setupFirebaseRemoteConfig.

Comment: [Others are seeing this crash](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/51) when the device does not have Play Services installed or perhaps an old version of Play Services.

Answer (score 0):

This error happen when you have different versions of play services or firebase in your dependencies. All versions must be the same, ex: 11.6.2

Answer (score 0):

Also, do check if your google-services.json is latest